# What happend for this pow() function in while loop C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find sum of all digit in number power three

such as 14 = 1^3 + 4^3 = 65

I try to code in c++ like this below but it's wrong if I use pow() function.

```
int number;
int sum = 0;

std::cin >> number;
while(number > 0) {
    sum += pow((number%10),3);
    number /= 10;
}
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
return 0;
```

for code above.
if input 153
output should be = 3^3 + 5^3 + 1^3 = 153
but actual output is 152

but this code below it's work very well, Why ? Thank you

```
int number;
int sum = 0;
std::cin >> number;
while(number > 0) {
   sum += (number % 10) * (number % 10) * (number % 10);
   number /= 10;
}
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pow(,) is a function that's meant for floating point calculations, so what you get as the primary result is a float. When you assign this result to an int, it is implicitly converted (cast) to an integer, meaning it has to get rid of all the decimals.

So if the primary result happens to be 27.999999998 or something due to finite accuracy of the calculation, this will be converted to the integer 27. This is because float->int cast always rounds towards zero (it was defined that way, presumably due to efficiency reasons).

Comment: Note that the finite accuracy is not due to `double`—integers that fit in 52 bits are represented in `double` exactly—but due to finite accuracy of the method used: the base C function takes `double` *exponent* and uses Taylor series or similar *approximate* method. C++ does have overload with integral exponent, but the standard library in use probably still forwards to the `double` C base. That might be the reason why @RaulAgrawal sees 153—their standard library might have exact calculation for that overload.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know there's an int overload.

Answer (score 2):

Function `pow` is for floating-point numbers and may loose precision when casted back to integer type. Try replacing it with `round(pow(number%10,3))`.